# Tennis Probability Match problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### ***Question:***

*A*'s chance of winning a set at tennis against *B* is $P_A=2/3$. Find his chance of winning at least 3 sets in a 5 set match,assuming that all 5 sets are to be played.

---

### ***My approach:***

Probability of A winning $$P_A=2/3$$

Probability of A losing: $$P_\bar A=P_B\ (Probability\ of\ B\ winning)=1/3$$
I cannot understand how to find the Probability by considering the winning and losing of *A* and *B* respectively. I tried googling for answers and also tried to search similar problems on mathematics stackexchange but no solution was available. And another interesting thing was that 3 answers were given for this problem but as per my knowledge, i think this question can have only 1 solution. This question is given in Frank Model Test Papers for Mathematics (Unsolved Model Test paper 14 ), question number 8.

---

### ***Given answer:***

$$1/2,\ 9/4,\ 2/3$$
Any help or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that the games are independent, you have to consider the cases:  $A$ wins exactly $3,4,5$.  Each is binomial.   Side question:  do you really think the answer might be $\frac 94$?

Comment: Can you provide an example with explanation?It would be super-helpful.By the way thanks for responding.

Comment: You can read about the binomial distribution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Example:  for exactly $3$ wins you get $\binom 53\times \left( \frac 23 \right)^3\times \left( \frac 13 \right)^2$

Comment: OK .Can you tell me whether this problem will have just 1 answer or 3 answers ,since in the book 3 answers have been provided for the problem.

Comment: Note:  doing it quickly, I don't get any of the proposed solutions.  Indeed, none of them seem possible.  $\frac 94$ is silly, $\frac 12$ is wrong as $A$ clearly has an advantage over $B$ and even $\frac 23$ is too low.

Comment: Of course it just has one answer.  And, as I say, the answer isn't any of the candidates.

Comment: Try to list the number of ways $A$ can win at least $3$ games. Then compute the probability of each possibility.

Comment: When you try to find a probability of a fact ("winning") start from it or it's opposite ("losing"). What u have to do is 1st consider in which cases he wins 3 games ex${(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,3,4).......(3,4,5)}$ the number of these combinations will eventually be $\binom 5 3$ each one has $(\frac{2}{3})^3=\frac{8}{27}$ winning-chance happening. The lose chance per game (2 loses) will be $(\frac{1}{3})^2=\frac{1}{9}$ what you have in whole is $\binom 5 3 * \frac{8}{27} * \frac{1}{9}$ if u generalize the above process you will get the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

All 5 sets will be played if and only if after the first 4 sets the game is tied. So assuming that all sets are played, the winning of player $A$ depends only if she wins the last set. And in this situation the winning of $A$ is equivalent to her winning at least 3 sets. Therefore

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{A wins at least 3 sets} \space | \space \text{All the 5 sets are played}) = \mathbb{P}(\text{A wins the last set}) =  \frac{2}{3}.$$